# cordova inappbrowser file upload android

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, inappbrowser

I don't know why but when I open my site with the inappbrowser and try to upload a file, the button isn't working at all.
The Ios version is working perfectly and when I open my site with the chrome app in the android phone the button is working.

There is something I missing?

Comment: input file doesn't work on android webview by default, you have to do some "hacks", so you should edit inAppBrowser source to make it work. And still those "hacks" don't work on some android versions (android 4.4-4.4.2). So, don't rely on inAppBrowser for your app logic, it should be used just to show external websites without leaving your app, but just displaying them

Comment: Here's an easy fix for this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42375766/1457709